# Confirmation of calculation: $\displaystyle \iint_S (yz\,\hat{\imath}+zx\,\hat{\jmath}+xy\,\hat{k})dS$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

The question goes like this:

> Evaluate $\displaystyle \iint_S (yz\,\hat{\imath}+zx\,\hat{\jmath}+xy\,\hat{k})\,dS$ where $S$ is the surface of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ in the first octant.

I saw this and my first thought was Stokes' theorem, but I considered the possibility of working through this "the hardest way possible".

The surface can be parametrized as follows: $S: f(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ \sqrt{a^2-(x^2+y^2)} \end{bmatrix} \begin{cases}0\le x \le \sqrt{a^2-y^2} \\ 0 \le y \le a\end{cases}$

The bound for $x$ is necessary as it is to ensure the bound is precisely defined.

While working through this I found it helpful to remember that $\sqrt{a^2-(x^2+y^2)}=z$. It's part of how I made this easier than surface integrals normally are.

\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \dfrac{-x}{\sqrt{a^2-(x^2+y^2)}} \end{bmatrix} \\
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} &= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ \dfrac{-y}{\sqrt{a^2-(x^2+y^2)}} \end{bmatrix} \\ \\
\hat{n}\,d\Sigma &= \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} \times \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} \\
&= \det\begin{pmatrix} \hat{\imath} & \hat{\jmath} & \hat{k} \\ 1 & 0 & \dfrac{-x}{\sqrt{a^2-(x^2+y^2)}} \\ 0 & 1 & \dfrac{-y}{\sqrt{a^2-(x^2+y^2)}} \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-(x^2+y^2)}} \\ \dfrac{y}{\sqrt{a^2-(x^2+y^2)}} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{x}{z} \\ \dfrac{y}{z} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \\ \\
\vec{F} \cdot \hat{n}\,d\Sigma &= \begin{bmatrix} yz \\ zx \\ xy \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{x}{z} \\ \dfrac{y}{z} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \\
&= xy + xy + xy \\
&= 3xy
\end{align}

So the whole integral simplifies to $\displaystyle \int_0^a \int_0^{\sqrt{a^2-y^2}} 3xy \,dx\,dy$.

Is this correct so far?

Comment: See this solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/192796/305862)

Comment: Yeah that checks out. Thanks!